# No route matches [DELETE] "/models.id" Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

I keep getting this error and I haven't found an answer here that addresses this error.

I have a Book, User and Like model stated like this:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title

  has_many :likes
  has_many :users, through: :likes
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :likes
  has_many :books, through: :likes
end

class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :book, :user

  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Corresponding likes controllers:

```
# app/controllers/likes_controller.rb
class LikesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    # Assign the logged in user to @user
    @user = current_user
    # Grab all of the books and put them into an array in @books
    @books = Book.all
  end

  def create 
    book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
    Like.create(:book => book, :user => current_user)
    redirect_to likes_path, :notice => "You just liked the book #{book.title}" 
  end

  def destroy
    like = Like.find(params[:id])
    like.destroy
    redirect_to likes_path, :notice => "You destroyed a like"
  end
end
```

In my config/routers.rb:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :likes

 end
```

I have link that is supposed to delete an existing like:

```
<% like = book.likes.where(:user_id => @user.id).first %>
 <%= link_to "destroy like", likes_path(like.id), :method => :delete %
```

But when I click the link, I get this error:

```
No route matches [DELETE] "/likes.7"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `likes_path(like.id)` to `like_path(like)` and enjoy :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error but for a different reason. I'm posting here as an answer in case someone else runs into this. In my case the problem was that I was using different controller than the model row I was trying to delete. I was using Users controller to delete a Checkout. Interestingly, I was able to delete a row from a third model (Course) with this code:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', c.course, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

but this did not work (and threw the error `No route matches [DELETE] "/checkouts.7"`)

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', c, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

The error was resolved when I moved code to use CheckoutsController and the associated view instead of UsersController. Must be Rails' way of forcing me to use the right controller.